# Assimp can't load other textures except diffuse texture of FBX

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, fbx, assimp

I try to load the FBX model in the last contains of this [learnopengl tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/PBR/IBL/Specular-IBL), but I only can load diffuse texture of the FBX. I had tried the solution of adjusting the order of layout in vertex shader, but it didn't work. The result of `material->GetTextureCount(type)` is 0 when type isn't `aiTextureType_DIFFUSE`.
Here is my code:

mesh.h

```cpp
#ifndef Mesh_h
#define Mesh_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include "ReviewShader.h"
struct Vertex{
    glm::vec3 Position;
    glm::vec3 Normal;
    glm::vec2 TexCoord;
};

struct Texture{
    unsigned int id;
    string type;
    string path;
};

class Mesh{
public:
    vector<Texture> textures;
    vector<unsigned int> indices;
    unsigned int VAO;
    Mesh(vector<Vertex> vertices, vector<Texture> textures, vector<unsigned int> indices){
        this->vertices = vertices;
        this->textures = textures;
        this->indices = indices;

        setupMesh();
    }

    void Draw(ReviewShader shader){
        int diffuseCount = 1;
        int specularCount = 1;
        int reflectionCount = 1;

        shader.use();
        for(int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++){
            string name = textures[i].type;
            string num;
            if(name == "texture_diffuse")
                num = to_string(diffuseCount++);
            else if(name == "texture_specular")
                num = to_string(specularCount++);
            else if(name == "texture_reflection")
                num = to_string(reflectionCount++);

            shader.setInt((name+num).c_str(), i);
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+i);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i].id);
        }
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
private:
    vector<Vertex> vertices;

    unsigned int VBO, EBO;

    void setupMesh(){
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * vertices.size(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, Normal));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, TexCoord));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

};
#endif /* Mesh_h */
```

model.h

```cpp
#ifndef Model_h
#define Model_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <string>

#include <vector>
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "ReviewShader.h"

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>

//#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb-master/stb_image.h>
vector<Texture> loaded_textures;

class Model{
public:
    vector<Mesh> meshes;
    string directory;

    Model(char *path){
        loadModel(path);
    }
    void Draw(ReviewShader shader){
        for(int i = 0; i < meshes.size(); i++){
            meshes[i].Draw(shader);
        }
    }
private:
    void loadModel(string path){
        Assimp::Importer importer;
//        const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_Triangulate);
        const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace);
        if(!scene || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode){
            cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP::" << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
            return;
        }
        directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of("/"));
        processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);

    }

    void processNode(aiNode *node, const aiScene *scene){
        for(int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++){
            aiMesh *mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
            meshes.push_back(processMesh(mesh, scene));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++){
            processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
        }
    }

    Mesh processMesh(aiMesh *mesh, const aiScene *scene){
        vector<Vertex> vertices;
        vector<Texture> textures;
        vector<unsigned int> indices;

        for(int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++){
            Vertex vertex;
            glm::vec3 vector;
            vector.x = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
            vertex.Position = vector;

            vector.x = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mNormals[i].z;
            vertex.Normal = vector;

            if(mesh->mTextureCoords[0]){
                glm::vec2 tex;
                tex.x = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
                tex.y = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
                vertex.TexCoord = tex;
            }
            else{
                vertex.TexCoord = glm::vec2(0.0, 0.0);
            }
            vertices.push_back(vertex);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++){
            aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++){
                indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
            }
        }

        aiMaterial *material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];
        vector<Texture> texture_diffuse = loadMaterialTexture(material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse");
        textures.insert(textures.end(), texture_diffuse.begin(), texture_diffuse.end());
        vector<Texture> texture_specular = loadMaterialTexture(material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular");
        textures.insert(textures.end(), texture_specular.begin(), texture_specular.end());
        vector<Texture> texture_ambient = loadMaterialTexture(material, aiTextureType_SHININESS, "texture_reflection");
        textures.insert(textures.end(), texture_ambient.begin(), texture_ambient.end());
        return Mesh(vertices, textures, indices);

    }

    vector<Texture> loadMaterialTexture(aiMaterial *material, aiTextureType type, string Typename){
        vector<Texture> textures;
        cout << material->GetTextureCount(type) << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < material->GetTextureCount(type); i++){
            bool skip = false;
            aiString str;
            material->GetTexture(type, i, &str);
            string tempStr = str.C_Str();
            tempStr.replace(tempStr.find("\\"), 1, "/");
            cout << tempStr << endl;

            for(int j = 0; j < loaded_textures.size(); j++){
                if(strcmp(loaded_textures[j].path.c_str(), tempStr.c_str()) == 0){
                    skip = true;
                    textures.push_back(loaded_textures[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!skip){
                Texture tex;
                tex.id = loadTextureFromFile(tempStr, directory);
                tex.type = Typename;
                tex.path = str.C_Str();
                textures.push_back(tex);
                loaded_textures.push_back(tex);
            }
        }
        return textures;
    }

    unsigned int loadTextureFromFile(string path, string &Directory){
        unsigned int textureID;
        glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        string filepath = Directory + "/" + path;
        int width, height, urChannel;
        unsigned char *data = stbi_load(filepath.c_str(), &width, &height, &urChannel, 0);
        if(data){
            GLenum format;
            if(urChannel == 1)
                format = GL_RED;
            if(urChannel == 3)
                format = GL_RGB;
            if(urChannel == 4)
                format = GL_RGBA;
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
        else{
            cout << "Read texture Data failed\n";
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
        return textureID;
    }
};
#endif /* Model_h */
```

model.vs

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aUV;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec2 UV;
out vec3 Position;

void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    UV = aUV;
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;
    Position = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));    
}
```

model.fs

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse;
uniform sampler2D texture_specular;
uniform sampler2D texture_roughness;

in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 UV;
in vec3 Position;

void main(){
    FragColor = texture(texture_diffuse, UV);
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <...>
...
using namespace std;


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
unsigned int loadTexture(const char *path);
unsigned int loadHDRTexture(char const * path);
unsigned int loadCubemap(vector<string> faces);
void renderQuad();
void renderCube();
void renderPlane();
void renderSphere();
float lerp(float a, float b, float scale);
// size settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(2.0, 4.0, -2.0);
glm::vec3 lightColor = glm::vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.7);

// calculation parameter
const float Pi = 3.14159265359;
const float doublePi = Pi * 2.0;


// camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f));
float lastX = (float)SCR_WIDTH  / 2.0;
float lastY = (float)SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

// texture normal
glm::vec3 normal(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

// plane normal
glm::vec3 planeNormal = glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);


int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    ...   

    // Create shaders
    ...
    ReviewShader modelShader("shader/model.vs", "shader/model.fs");

    // pbr configure
    ...

    Model gunModel = Model("Gun_Model/Cerberus_LP.FBX");

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // avoid delay
        // -----------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // process input
        // -------------
        processInput(window);
        glViewport(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH * 2, SCR_HEIGHT * 2);
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.getViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        modelShader.use();
        model = glm::mat4(1.0);
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.1));
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-90.0f), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        modelShader.setMat4("model", model);
        modelShader.setMat4("view", view);
        modelShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        gunModel.Draw(modelShader);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first: which version of the Asset-Importer-Lib do you use? We made a lot of improvements in the FBX-Importer, so switching to the latest 5.0-release is strongly recommended.

Normally when the number of textures shows zero it is a sign that there is only one texture used in our model. To verify that yo can just use Blender, The interal Asset-Importer-Viewer or the Editor of the Godot-Engine to check that your model is right.

If there is more than just a diffuse-texture stored in your model please create a new issue report here: [Assimp-Bugtracker](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues) . And please add a model which we can use to reproduce the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From where did you get the version?

Comment: Thank you so much. I find that my version isn't latest. I will try the latest version. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.

I use win 10's 3D Viewer to see that there are no textures aside from the albedo texture, so the problem is not with ASSIMP but rather with the Cerberus_LP.FBX file. You can just bind the textures manually, as they are in the "Textures" folder in the same directory.

Also, if someone wants to use 3D Viewer to check textures, just open the object with the program and click the middle tab in the right panel, the middle tab is the one that says, "Stats & Shading".